# How to update my cpp comments using BufWritePre

Tags: vim

I'm putting some code in my .vimrc to automatically update the "Last Update" field on my .cpp and .h files documentation.

I've tried it for my .py files and it worked. The problem is searching the line that starts with the characters `*  Last Update`. Here's what I have so far:

The comments in my cpp file

```cpp
/**
 * @file  test.cpp
 * @author  John Doe
 * @version
 * @brief
 * @date
 *  Created:  21 mai 2019
 *  Last Update:
 */
```

and my .vimrc

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.h exe "%s/^ \*  Last Update:.*$/Last Update: " 
      \. strftime("%d %b %Y (%T)") . "/e"
```

This should update the comments to:

```cpp
/**
 * @file  test.cpp
 * @author  John Doe
 * @version
 * @brief
 * @date
 *  Created:  21 mai 2019
 *  Last Update:  21 mai 2019 (21:15:48)
 */
```

But I got no changes at all.

Update: I have the same code in my header files (.h)

Comment: The autocmd has `*.h` and the example file is `test.cpp`. Is it just in your example here? if yes, please update the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I updated my answer to work with `.h` files too.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to work with `.cpp` **and** `.h` files

You need to add the following to your `.vimrc` or other file that gets sourced:

```
autocmd FileType cpp,h autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :%s/^ \*  Last Update:.*$/\=printf(' *  Last Update: ') . strftime("%d %b %Y (%T)")/e
```

`autocmd FileType cpp,h`

- makes sure, that it works only for `.cpp` or `.h` files

`autocmd BufwritePre <buffer>`

- writes to the current buffer

`:%s/^ \*  Last Update:.*$/`

- that's the begin of the replacing command in which the pattern to be replaced is stated

`\=printf(' *  Last Update: ') . strftime("%d %b %Y (%T)")/e`

- this is the {replacement} and the end of the replacing command

When the {replacement} starts with `\=` it is evaluated as an expression. 
As a string is no expression `printf` is needed to output the first part of the string. The two functions `printf` and `strftime` are then concatenated via `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\zs` trick to match just after the `:`

```
:%s/\vlast (modified|change):?\zs.*/\=" " . strftime('%d %b %Y (%T)')/ei
```

The flags are `e` to ignore errors, and `i` to ignore case. Read about `\zs`at `:h \zs`